# Failed to create target binding for binding SelectedItem

Tags: mvvmcross

I try to bind the selected item of a MvxListView to my property. This is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_search_text"
            local:MvxBind="Text SearchText" />
        <MvxListView
            android:id="@+id/category_list"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_category"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Categories; SelectedItem SelectedCategory" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The ItemSource here is properly bound.

ViewModel:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class SelectCategoryListViewModel : AbstractCategoryListViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates an CategoryListViewModel for the usage of providing a category selection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="categoryRepository">An instance of <see cref="IRepository{T}" /> of type category.</param>
    /// <param name="dialogService">An instance of <see cref="IDialogService" /></param>
    public SelectCategoryListViewModel(IRepository<Category> categoryRepository,
        IDialogService dialogService) : base(categoryRepository, dialogService)
    {}

    public Category SelectedCategory { get; set; }

    public MvxCommand DoneCommand => new MvxCommand(Done);

    public MvxCommand CancelCommand => new MvxCommand(Cancel);

    private void Done()
    {
        MessageHub.Publish(new CategorySelectedMessage(this, SelectedCategory));
        Close(this);
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        Close(this);
    }
}
```

Not the notify PropertyChanged is done via Fody and Categories are in the parent VM.

```
public class SelectCategoryListActivity : MvxFragmentCompatActivity<SelectCategoryListViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.fragment_category_list);

        SetSupportActionBar(FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar));
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
...
```

The Warning I get is:

[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  5.11 Failed to create target binding for binding SelectedItem for SelectedCategory

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across a similar issue with a `SelectedItem` binding failing. The solve was to update Mvx to version 4.1.6. The reason being is that you need to register `MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories`, with 4.1.6 this is now done automatically.

Alternatively, you can manually register it in you setup.cs by overriding `FillTargetFactories`:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
}
```